# Shiny application not showing datatable after several hours

Tags: r, shiny

I am experiencing weird behaviour in my Shiny application. Once deployed it runs for several hours and then I stop seeing the datatable. 
Once I update ui.R with any change to force reload of the application everything is back to normal.

server.R

```
source("helper.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$report_table = renderDataTable({
  render_main_table(get_data())
})
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(dataTableOutput('report_table')))
```

helper.R

```
require(shiny)
require(data.table)
require(DT)
get_data <- function() {
    return (fread("data/report.csv"))  
}
render_main_table <- function(data) {
    return (datatable(data))
}
```

I have looked on the websocket communication after the site stops working and I can see that the response from the server contains correct column names but no data.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" and "stop seeing the datatable"? Do you mean the session timeout from shiny server / shinyapps.io?

Comment: I am using my own Shiny Server Pro. When I say not working I mean the datatable is not shown.

Comment: So it shows up when the page loads, but mysteriously disappears (blank white box?) after leaving it up for a few hours?

Comment: Yes, refreshing the page does not fix the situation.

Comment: That is weird indeed. Without seeing the actual app, I have no idea, but maybe there's a small chance it's related to https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/489. Not sure which version of DT you're using, but listing that could help.

Comment: Added extra comment on websocket communication.